# Is it impossible to earn the Fanatic badge twice?

Tags: discussion, badges

I received the Fanatic badge a while back.  Today I've been on the site for another 100 consecutive days, but I haven't earned the badge.  Looking over the list of all the people who've gotten this badge, no one has it 2x.  Is it impossible to earn this badge twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't get the [Fanatic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/badges/23/fanatic) badge twice. You didn't get [Enthusiast](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/badges/22/enthusiast) 6 times for 180 days either. There's no badge beyond Fanatic; all you get is the increasing “consecutive days” number in your profile.

The [badge FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) on the main meta site explains precisely what it takes to get the various badges, and mentions which ones can be obtained multiple times.

Comment: Curses, foiled again!